# Function or Equation Help

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Could I please get some help on creating a function or equation that reflects the starting number say "x" in overall resulting growth with reoccurring decay in a set pattern.

```
x input = y output, where z is added to y from 
the previous output of y to get the next number

"x"           "y"          "z"             
0   =   -1,027,423,550                  Where the 64th number changes 
1   =   -1,027,423,549      1           in this sequence and then repeats
2   =   -1,027,423,552      -3          the cycle back starting at 389 infintely
3   =   -1,027,423,551      1           -123
4   =   -1,027,423,546      5           -123
5   =   -1,027,423,545      1           -123
6   =   -1,027,423,548      -3          389
7   =   -1,027,423,547      1           -123
8   =   -1,027,423,542      5           -123
9   =   -1,027,423,541      1           -123
10  =   -1,027,423,544      -3          -635
11  =   -1,027,423,543      1           -123
12  =   -1,027,423,538      5           -123
13  =   -1,027,423,537      1           -123
14  =   -1,027,423,540      -3          389
15  =   -1,027,423,539      1           -123
16  =   -1,027,423,534      5           -123
17  =   -1,027,423,533      1           -123
18  =   -1,027,423,536      -3          1413
19  =   -1,027,423,535      1           -123
20  =   -1,027,423,530      5           -123
21  =   -1,027,423,529      1           -123
22  =   -1,027,423,532      -3          
23  =   -1,027,423,531      1           
24  =   -1,027,423,526      5           
25  =   -1,027,423,525      1           
26  =   -1,027,423,528      -3          
27  =   -1,027,423,527      1           
28  =   -1,027,423,522      5           
29  =   -1,027,423,521      1           
30  =   -1,027,423,524      -3          
31  =   -1,027,423,523      1           
32  =   -1,027,423,518      5           
33  =   -1,027,423,517      1           
34  =   -1,027,423,520      -3          
35  =   -1,027,423,519      1           
36  =   -1,027,423,514      5           
37  =   -1,027,423,513      1           
38  =   -1,027,423,516      -3          
39  =   -1,027,423,515      1           
40  =   -1,027,423,510      5           
41  =   -1,027,423,509      1           
42  =   -1,027,423,512      -3          
43  =   -1,027,423,511      1           
44  =   -1,027,423,506      5           
45  =   -1,027,423,505      1           
46  =   -1,027,423,508      -3          
47  =   -1,027,423,507      1           
48  =   -1,027,423,502      5           
49  =   -1,027,423,501      1           
50  =   -1,027,423,504      -3          
51  =   -1,027,423,503      1           
52  =   -1,027,423,498      5           
53  =   -1,027,423,497      1           
54  =   -1,027,423,500      -3          
55  =   -1,027,423,499      1           
56  =   -1,027,423,494      5           
57  =   -1,027,423,493      1           
58  =   -1,027,423,496      -3          
59  =   -1,027,423,495      1           
60  =   -1,027,423,490      5           
61  =   -1,027,423,489      1           
62  =   -1,027,423,492      -3          
63  =   -1,027,423,491      1           
64  =   -1,027,423,614      -123            
65  =   -1,027,423,613      1           
66  =   -1,027,423,616      -3          
67  =   -1,027,423,615      1           
68  =   -1,027,423,610      5           
69  =   -1,027,423,609      1           
70  =   -1,027,423,612      -3          
71  =   -1,027,423,611      1           
72  =   -1,027,423,606      5           
73  =   -1,027,423,605      1           
74  =   -1,027,423,608      -3          
75  =   -1,027,423,607      1           
76  =   -1,027,423,602      5           
77  =   -1,027,423,601      1           
78  =   -1,027,423,604      -3          
79  =   -1,027,423,603      1           
80  =   -1,027,423,598      5           
81  =   -1,027,423,597      1           
82  =   -1,027,423,600      -3          
83  =   -1,027,423,599      1           
84  =   -1,027,423,594      5           
85  =   -1,027,423,593      1           
86  =   -1,027,423,596      -3          
87  =   -1,027,423,595      1           
88  =   -1,027,423,590      5           
89  =   -1,027,423,589      1           
90  =   -1,027,423,592      -3          
91  =   -1,027,423,591      1           
92  =   -1,027,423,586      5           
93  =   -1,027,423,585      1           
94  =   -1,027,423,588      -3          
95  =   -1,027,423,587      1           
96  =   -1,027,423,582      5           
97  =   -1,027,423,581      1           
98  =   -1,027,423,584      -3          
99  =   -1,027,423,583      1           
100 =   -1,027,423,578      5           
101 =   -1,027,423,577      1           
102 =   -1,027,423,580      -3          
103 =   -1,027,423,579      1           
104 =   -1,027,423,574      5           
105 =   -1,027,423,573      1           
106 =   -1,027,423,576      -3          
107 =   -1,027,423,575      1           
108 =   -1,027,423,570      5           
109 =   -1,027,423,569      1           
110 =   -1,027,423,572      -3          
111 =   -1,027,423,571      1           
112 =   -1,027,423,566      5           
113 =   -1,027,423,565      1           
114 =   -1,027,423,568      -3          
115 =   -1,027,423,567      1           
116 =   -1,027,423,562      5           
117 =   -1,027,423,561      1           
118 =   -1,027,423,564      -3          
119 =   -1,027,423,563      1           
120 =   -1,027,423,558      5           
121 =   -1,027,423,557      1           
122 =   -1,027,423,560      -3          
123 =   -1,027,423,559      1           
124 =   -1,027,423,554      5           
125 =   -1,027,423,553      1           
126 =   -1,027,423,556      -3          
127 =   -1,027,423,555      1           
128 =   -1,027,423,678      -123
```

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 1):

$$y=-1027423550+x-2+2\sqrt2\sin\Bigl(\frac\pi4+x\frac\pi2\Bigr)$$

Comment: Good evening, thx so much for putting time into this for me. So I'm not sure if its me, but could you please try doing running the equation for values of x of 1466 and/or 153. When I ran through it and double checked my excel table I found that when ( x=1466, y=-1,027,422,344) and when (x=153, y=-1,027,423,653). But the Equation was saying ( x=1466, y=-1,027,422,084) and when (x=153, y=-1,027,423,401). Would more data points from larger values help?

Comment: If it doesn't work I can't offer any more suggestions.  Just substitute $x$ values into the formula and do the calculation.  Make sure your calculator is using radians not degrees.

Comment: Oh I'll have to double check that. I think I was using degrees. Thank you